# Importing a third party framework into Xcode 6 – how do I save it to my project?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, gpuimage

I'm trying to add the GPUImage library to my project, and I'm following the [directions given on the GitHub page](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#adding-this-as-a-framework-module-to-your-mac-or-ios-project) to use it with Swift.

I drop the .xcodeproj in, but it appears to just link to where it is in my `~/Downloads` folder. How do I add it to my project itself? Where is the proper place to add a framework into a project? Am I even doing it correctly by dragging the xcodeproj into the main xcodeproj of my app?

Comment: I HIGHLY suggest importing third party frameworks using CocoaPods instead. It will take maybe a twenty minutes to set them up (at most) and will save you hours & hours in the future.

Comment: @AdamPro13 I do use CocoaPods, but the developer of GPUImage doesn't seem like a big fan. I encountered a bug with it today, and upon searching it seems to be [documented](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1808) but unfixed in the main release (and per his suggestion, isn't pulling from the most recent version of the repo bad, as it doesn't allow you to freeze to a working version?). I can't help but feel the developer isn't a fan of CocoaPods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually do this is to set up a directory for the framework at the same directory level as your application project (ex: ~/Development/GPUImage, ~/Development/YourProject). I prefer to have the code for the framework outside of the code for my projects for cleanliness of version control, but that's a matter of personal preference.

The instructions for the setup of the framework assume that you already have a set location for your GPUImage code in your filesystem (~/Downloads is probably not that place). Pulling in the .xcodeproj merely links to that location. You'll also need to know that location to set where the framework header search path is.